# How to see config values

Tags: h2

I can set some configs and variables like:

```sql
SET COMPRESS_LOB LZF
```

How can I see what value a property was set to? Something like:

```sql
SELECT COMPRESS_LOB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables [here](https://www.h2database.com/html/systemtables.html).

```
select value from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS where NAME='COMPRESS_LOB';
```